# Can I visit my own garrison with an alt?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a character with a garrison.

Is there any way that I can visit this garrison with my alts (same server, same faction)?

---

Why do I want to do this? I have everything that I need/want in this garrison (bank, AH, void storage, portals, etc.) and being able to access it with my alts would be very useful to me. Much better than visiting major cities and needing to run all around them to get to what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't.

If both chars are on the same WoW account, that is. If you have multiple accounts, then chars from different accounts can visit each other by playing them simultaneously.

Comment: Yeah but you wouldn't be able to use any of the buildings anyway.